# Powershell - Show ACTIVE users who are member of ADMINISTRATORS group

Tags: powershell

I have cause for a single-line copy/paste script to show local accounts that are members of the Administrators group, but only if the accounts are active.

I can't do this with DOS commands net user, mainly because the output of net localgroup isn't suitable for parsing and all the echoing to the screen. (Here's the one-liner for this method though)

```
echo: & echo ^>^>^> LOCAL ADMINS (Active) ^<^<^< & echo: & for /f "delims=" %i in ('net localgroup administrators') do (for /f "delims=" %j in ('net user "%i" 2^>nul ^| find /i "Account active" ^| find /i "Yes"') do (echo *** %i))
```

I **can** do this in Powershell using Get-LocalGroupMember and Get-LocalUser. However, this doesn't work on all computers (especially Windows 7, or those that have been upgraded to Windows 10 because the cmdlets aren't installed). (This is the one-liner for this method though)

```
Write-Host "`r`n'>>> LOCAL ADMINS (Active) <<<'`r`n"; Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators ^|% { Get-LocalUser ($_.Name).split('\')[1] ^|? Enabled ^|%  {Write-Host "'***'$($_.Name)"}}
```

I've tried to use the Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount and Win32_GroupUser functions which seem to work regardless of Windows operating system and age, but this is the one I can't work out.

I can retrieve a list of enabled users but don't know how to test for membership of the Administrators group. This is what I have at the moment.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount ^|? {$_.Disabled -eq $false} ^|% { $_.Name }
```

Comment: I did actually find a way to make it work in DOS, but you have to type "echo on" to use the window again. And if you put "& echo on" at the end of the one-liner, it ignores the beginning "@echo off" command. I'll post the code in the next comment. Is there a way to make the echo behave properly?

Comment: @echo off & echo: & echo ^>^>^> LOCAL ADMINS (Active) ^<^<^< & echo: & for /f "delims=" %i in ('net localgroup administrators') do (for /f "delims=" %j in ('net user "%i" 2^>nul ^| find /i "Account active" ^| find /i "Yes"') do (echo *** %i))

Answer (score 0):

I think this PowerShell script will do the job on Windows 7 workstations :

```
# Retrieve NTDomain using Win32_ComputerSystem
$ComputerDomain = ((Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain).Split(".")[0]

# Retrieve members of Administrators group using Win32_Group.Domain
$Admins = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent=`"Win32_Group.Domain='$ENV:Computername',Name='administrators'`""
$users = @()

# cut PartComponent format : \\PC001\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="PC001",Name="Administrator"
foreach ($member in $Admins) {

    $partComponent = $member.PartComponent
    $namespace = $partComponent.Split(":")[0]
    $class = $partComponent.Split(":")[1].Split(".")[0]
    $memberDomain = $partComponent.Split(":")[1].Split(".")[1].Split(",")[0].Split("`"")[1]
    $memberName = $partComponent.Split(":")[1].Split(".")[1].Split(",")[1].Split("`"")[1]
    $users += $class + ":" + $memberDomain + "\" + $memberName
}

#Assemblies for domain accounts
Add-Type -assembly "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"
Add-Type -assembly "System.Security.Principal"

$ActivesAdmins = @()

foreach ($user in $users) {

    $UserType = $User.Split(":")[0]
    $UserDomain = $user.Split(":")[1].Split("\")[0]
    $UserName = $user.Split("\")[1]

    #Domain accounts
    If (($UserType -eq "Win32_UserAccount") -and ($UserDomain -eq $ComputerDomain)) {
        $ActiveUser = $null
        $ActiveUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal("$UserName") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($activeUser -ne $null) {$ActivesAdmins += $UserDomain + "\" + $UserName}
    }
    #Local accounts
    ElseIf (($UserType -eq "Win32_UserAccount") -and ($UserDomain -eq $env:ComputerName)) {
        $DisabledUser = $null
        $DisabledUser = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$UserName"} | ForEach-Object { $_.Disabled }
        If ($DisabledUser -eq $False) {$ActivesAdmins += $UserDomain + "\" + $UserName}
    }
}
Write-Host "List of Actives Admins :"
$ActivesAdmins
```